# twilio. An error occurs when deploying with plugin

Tags: twilio

If you deploy using the command below,
twilio flex:plugins:deploy --changelog='first deploy'

The following error will occur.
I don't understand the meaning of the path pointed to by resource.

Error code 20404 from Twilio: The requested resource /Services/ZSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Environments was not found. See https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404 for more info.

This is the first deployment that has not been deployed yet.
What should i do?

twilio serverless:deploy

Using the above command, functions and assets are deployed on a serverless basis.
At that time, I have deleted the Services of functions and assets that existed by default.

Is this default Services relevant for plugins?
Also, if it is related, where is the part to reset in the plug-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I contacted support, they told me to run the reset command.

```
curl  https://flex-api.twilio.com/v1/Configuration \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"account_sid":"ACCOUNT_SID", "serverless_service_sids": []}' \
-u ACCOUNT_SID:AUTH_TOKEN
```

If you deploy again after executing the above command
I was able to deploy without problems.

Comment: It does not work for me.

Comment: I also don't know what is being reset internally by this command.
If you contact the Twilio support team, it will take some time, but I think it will be resolved!